# Is below subspace is connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

**Question**: the **subspace** $\mathbb{Q}×[0,1]$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$(with usual topology) is connected?

I know the definition of connected set but yet I had solve the examples of $\mathbb{R}$. I know $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected. So I think given subspace will be disconnected. But, **this is not the proof**! To prove: the **subspace** $\mathbb{Q}×[0,1]$ is disconnected, we have to express it as disjoint union of two non-empty open sets in subspace topology! But as a beginner, I can't able do this!

please anyone help me to prove it is disconnected! I am stuck on this from hours and i don't want to skip proof.

Answer (score 3):

**This is a hint, not a solution.**

Hint: Let's call your set $X$, just to give it a name.

1. Can you show that $\Bbb Q$ is disconnected by exhibiting nonempty open sets $U$ and $V$ with $\Bbb Q = U \cup V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$?
2. If you can, then $U_1 = U \times \Bbb R$ and $V_1 = V \times \Bbb R$ are both open. (Why?)
3. $U' = U_1 \cap X$, and $V' = V_1 \cap X$ are both open subsets of $X$ in the subspace topology. (Why?)
4. $U'$ and $V'$ are nonempty.

You take it from here.

Comment: Sir, for (1): if we let $U= (-∞, r)$ and $V=(r, ∞)$ where $r$ is irrational number then is am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: and then (2): $U_1=(-∞,r)×\mathbb{R}$ and $V_1=(r,∞)×\mathbb{R}$ but sir why this are open (because as Cartesian product of open sets is open) ?

Comment: See "product topology" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology). The second paragraph under "Definition" is particularly relevant.

Comment: Sir, please help needed in (4) ...

Comment: And for your next question, which I can magically foretell: see "Subspace topology" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). :)

Comment: Suppose we pick, in your first comment, that $r = \pi$. Then $(1, 0.5) \in U'$, and $(4, 0.5) \in V'$.

Comment: Sir, whether we had proved they are disjoint(already)? I mean $U'$ and $V'$ are disjoint? How to see this?

Comment: Suppose that $(q, s)$ is in both $U'$ and $V'$. Then $(q, s)$ is in both $U_1$ and $V_1$. Now what can you say about the number $q$?

Comment: $(q,s)$ is in both $U_1$ and $V_1$ but i think $U_1$ and $V_1$ are disjoint. ?

Comment: OK. I've led you far enough, and I have to go do something else. You can work things out from here; it's no longer a matter of topology, but simply one of sets and their elements. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much sir...

Comment: Sir, i think I had done mistake in my first comment. we must take $U= \mathbb{Q}∩(-∞,r)$ and $V=\mathbb{Q}∩(r, ∞)$ where $r$ is irrational. is am I correct?

Comment: Sure -- that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looking over the comments to John Hughes' answer, I see that you were advised to study how the definitions and properties of connected\subspace\product play out together.

With that as the background, the problem can be tackled by finding a nonempty and proper subset of $D = \mathbb{Q}×[0,1]$ that is both open and closed.

So we want to find an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and a closed set of $C$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that

$\tag 1 \emptyset \ne U \cap D = C \cap D \ne D$

There are two candidates that practically 'jump out' for inspection:

$\quad U = (\sqrt2, +\infty) \times \mathbb R$

and

$\quad C = [\sqrt2, +\infty) \times \mathbb R\;$ (recall that the product of two closed sets is closed)

We leave it to the OP to wrap up any loose ends.

Comment: Sir, thanks for answering, but I couldn't get your answer. As for showing disconnectedness one must show, "given set is union of two disjoint nonempty open sets. But you had find one open set $U$ and one closed set $C$. "How" problem can be tackled by finding a nonempty and proper subset of $D$ which are both open and closed. Didn't get the purpose, could you please elaborate. ...:-(

Comment: Let $U$ be a nontrivial open subset of a topological space $X$ that is also closed. Then the complement of $U$ is open. But then $X$ has a nontrivial decomposition/partition, $X = U \cup complement(U)$ into two open sets.

Comment: and sir here the clopen that you had find is $U∩D=C∩D$. am I correct?

Comment: And as John said "it's no longer a matter of topology, but simply one of sets and their elements". You have all these facts about topological spaces, but for many elementary questions, it finally gets reduced to exercising logic and working with relations and truths about sets.

Comment: and sir here the clopen that you had find is $U∩D=C∩D$. am I correct?

Comment: Yes. By the usual subspace definition $U \cap D$ is open in $D$, but it also true that  $C \cap D$ is closed in $D$ when $C$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir ..."Beautiful Answer" :-)